# How to Avoid CGI Timeout?

Tags: php, apache, timeout, cgi, fastcgi

I have a PHP process which the user runs in the browser, but tends to take a fairly long time  - upwards of 5 minutes. We just switched to a new server, and when we try to run the script now, it consistently times out at 4 minutes exactly, sending to a 500 Internal Server Error page and outputting the following errors in the error log:

> Timeout waiting for output from CGI
>   script
>
> Premature end of script headers:
>   cgi_wrapper

What's interesting is that the PHP process does seem to complete in the background. If we navigate away from the 500 Error page and wait a bit, the desired changes from the script do get made.

Is there any way to unhinge this CGI limit which seems to have been placed on us? I have read about FastCGI, but am not sure how to install this on our server (Apache, centOS, PHP 5.3).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the web server times out waiting for a response from the script. Actually with four minutes the server seems to be pretty patient. The default for FastCGI connections is 30 seconds.

It may help sending (and `flush()`ing) some data to the client while he is waiting. This tells both the web server and the browser that the request is still alive.

For example, if your script serves a HTML page at the end you may send a `<!-- please wait... ->` from time to time. It won't be visible to the user.

Anyway, any script that takes more than 10 seconds to complete is bad design. I suggest doing that work in the background in a separate process and have the client poll the completion status. Be aware that some browsers / proxies may time out the request no matter what you do on the server.